# Incorrect AngularJS data calculation algorithm

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I think i will just straight to the point

So, now I have an input field

```
balance 
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.data.collection_amount">
```

and Payment Amount field(which is in an array)

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.payment_amount" ng-change="vm.calculateAmount(item)">
```

Then i have list of payment which is in an array

```
(vm.invoice)
```

To each of the payment list row, there are a checkbox and then an input field for the amount of payment.

This is the work flow :

> 1. User input the amount balance he wants to pay. For example he adds balance $20
> 2. Then there will be a list of payment he has to pay. Let's say he has 2 payments that he has to pay.
> 3. 1st is $100, and 2nd is $150

All I want to achieve is the validation for another invoice.

I have this code

```
var co_amount = parseFloat(vm.data.collection_amount).toFixed(2);
//co_amount is $20;

if(item.checkbox == true){
            console.log("checkbox : true");
            if(vm.data.collection_amount == null || vm.data.collection_amount == undefined || vm.data.collection_amount == ''){
                item.payment_amount = 0;
            }
            else{
                if(vm.data.collection_amount > 0){
                    vm.data.collection_amount = 0;
                    item.payment_amount = co_amount;
                }
                else
                    item.payment_amount = 0;
            }
        }
else{
            console.log("checkbox : false");
            vm.data.collection_amount = co_amount;
            item.payment_amount = 0;
}
```

Now, if I toggle the 1st invoice checkbox, the payment amount will be filled automatically by the balance amount which is $20 and the balance amount will become $0, and if i unchecked the checkbox, the payment amount will become 0 and then the balance amount will back to $20 (which is no problem, vice versa).

And then I checked the 1st invoice, then, checked 2nd invoice, the 2nd invoice payment amount will become 0, which is correct, because the balance amount is already 0. However, if I unchecked the 2nd invoice back with 1st invoice is checked, the balance amount will back to $20, which is false! I found out that there is something missing in the if else statement, but i couldn't figure out what to do.

What I want is that

> When User Unchecked the second Invoice. The Balance Amount is still
>   $0. Without coming back to $20. 
>       In current condition, The Balance Amount will back to $20 because of the else statement.

I have been dealing with this for several hours. And it really frustrates me.

I know there is more validation to be done, but I cant move on because this is the "first" step.

Can somebody point out what to do? Thank you so much

Comment: create  fiddle or plunker it will be easy to fix

Comment: sir i am new to this kind of stuffs. I have never used a fiddle or plunker, but i will try it now

Comment: its girl not sir @Foster

Comment: can you provide full code?